# Missing properties (Globalds) from IFC file in viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

To resume the steps leading to my issue:

1. Upload a file to bucket in Forge.
2. Convert the file.
3. Extract the IFC data using external tool.

Now I am trying to get (using the Viewer) the GlobalIds of each element, as in IFC they are unique and match them to the data that I already have by this property.

Currently in the converted file that is shown in the viewer, not all the elements from the geometry are providing the correct data on click.
For example: If I open a IFC file in viewer and I click on the Roof element, it does not select the IfcRoof element, but some IfcElement that is lower in the structure and that neither have a GlobalId, nor has some data attached, cause it is not supposed to. So now it is not possible to get the proper properties of the element using the viewer because it does not selects the right element, which I need to match the data that I extract with the external tool.

Any ideas how I can proceed with that?

Comment: Hi, As I know IFC is passing through NWD translation and gets a standard NavisWorks **externalId** of the form 0/1/2/3/2/3... externalId is not in the result.properties array, it’s in the dedicated result.externalId property. Same applies for AutoCAD handle/AcDbId/Revit UniqueID.

Comment: Can you please let me know if we can get Element ID from IFC file in C#, right now I am using XBIM dlls from nuget packages, but I am getting only Global IDs which changes for each element on multiple exports. Any suggestions will be a lot of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you simply traverse the structure from the lower level element upwards until you reach an element that does provide a valid global id?

Comment: I need the exact selected element with the GlobalId, and I get it for some. In IFC some elements can be inherited but here we get types like IFCBOOLEANCLIPPINGRESULT instead of IFCWALL, or IFCSHAPEREPRESENTATION instead of IFCWINDOW. Don't think this is expected.

Comment: have you checked the externalId property suggested above by Xiaodong?

Comment: Yes, for IFC it is still of type (0/2/4) which don't help.

Comment: The auto generated unique path id like 1/2/3/0 is internal structure of the Navisworks scene. I am waiting for the further reply from our engineer team if there is any algorism of the mapping from GlobalID and the externalID. I will update this thread when there is any news.

Answer (score 0):

So the clue is that you should iterate the response's __parent's till you get an element with type 'IFC' and get his GlobalId. It works in most cases.

Comment: yes, you are right! Our engineer team also confirmed that there is no equation between the externalID of LMV and GlobalID. The IFC uses the extractor of Navisworks. That id format of externalID is provided by Navisworks. You'd have to iterate all objects and make a mapping. What I was stuck is with my test IFC file, I did not find a property of GlobalID with the object, so I was keeping checking with the engineer team on that, but finally it looks my IFC is special. With typical IFC file, Global ID is available as what you saw in the object properties.